# Retrieve video file duration (time) using R

Tags: r, video

I’m creating a code to delete some video files that I don’t need.  The videos are from CCTV footage and  they record 24/7. However the software that records the video saves the files in ~1 hour videos and this is the problem (not being exact duration).  I’m only interested in keeping videos from a particular part of the day (which varies) and because the duration of the video is not exact this is causing me problems.

The video file name has a date and time stamp but only for the start so if I could find the duration everything becomes simple algebra.

So my question is simple is it possible to get the duration (time) of video files using R?

Just a couple of other useful information the videos are from several cameras and each camera as a different recording  frame rate so using file.info to return the file size and derive the length of the video is not an option.  Also the video files are in  .avi format.

Cheers
Patrao

Comment: You could write a VirtualDub script and run that on each file?

Comment: If you're on linux, try http://askubuntu.com/questions/303454/get-information-about-a-video-from-command-line-tool

Comment: @Roman Unfortunately I cant't write VirtualDub code and I'm on windows 7 system.

Comment: What codec are these AVI files using? Are they constant bit rate?

Comment: @MultimediaMike I'm afraid I don't know the answer to either of the questions. I obviously underestimated the complexity of my question...

Comment: Are you comfortable reading and interpreting binary data via R? You could probably do some parsing of the AVI header to get the necessary data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no ready packages that handle video files in R (like matlab does). This isn't a pure R solution, but gets the job done. I installed CLI interface to [MediaInfo](https://superuser.com/questions/597626/windows-get-duration-of-video-file-from-command-line) and called it from R. I called it using `system`.

```
wolf <- system("q:/mi_cli/mediainfo.exe Krofel_video2volk2.AVI", intern = TRUE)
wolf # output by MediaInfo

[1] "General"                                                            
 [2] "Complete name                            : Krofel_video2volk2.AVI"  
 [3] "Format                                   : AVI"                     
 [4] "Format/Info                              : Audio Video Interleave"  
 [5] "File size                                : 10.7 MiB"                
 [6] "Duration                                 : 11s 188ms"               
 [7] "Overall bit rate                         : 8 016 Kbps"              
 ...        
[37] "Channel count                            : 1 channel"               
[38] "Sampling rate                            : 8 000 Hz"                
[39] "Bit depth                                : 16 bits"                 
[40] "Stream size                              : 174 KiB (2%)"            
[41] "Alignment                                : Aligned on interleaves"  
[42] "Interleave, duration                     : 63 ms (1.00 video frame)"

# Find where Duration is (general) and extract it.
find.duration <- grepl("Duration", wolf)
wolf[find.duration][1]# 1 = General, 2 = Video, 3 = Audio
[1] "Duration                                 : 11s 188ms"
```

Have fun parsing the time.

Comment: I’m getting a warning message “Running command C:\\Users\\Documents\\MediaInfo\\MediaInfo.exe teste.avi" had status 1” for which I can’t find a solution. Have you came across this before? However If I run the command strait from the CLI everything run’s just fine so I’m assuming it’s not MediaInfo related. Cheers

Comment: I get the error when I run: system("C:\\Users\\Documents\\MediaInfo\\MediaInfo.exe teste.avi", intern = TRUE)

Comment: @PatraoPedro is `teste.avi` in `getwd()`?

Comment: I’ve tried it two different ways one where the test.avi is inside of the MediaInfo folder wolf<-system("C:\\Users\\Documents\\MediaInfo\\MediaInfo.exe teste.avi", intern = TRUE) and another giving the true paths wolf <- system("C:\\Users\\catarinor\\Documents\\MediaInfo\\MediaInfo.exe C:\\Users\\Desktop\\New folder\\teste.avi", intern = TRUE)

Comment: @PatraoPedro set working directory to where teste.avi is and try again.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit low level, but if you're up to the task of parsing binary data, look up a copy of the AVI spec and figure out how to get both the number of video frames and the frame rate.

If you look at one of the AVI files using a hex editor, you will see a series of `LIST` chunks at the beginning. A little farther into this chunk will be a `vids` chunk. Immediately following `vids` should be a human-readable video four-character code (FourCC) specifying the video codec, probably something like `mjpg` (MJPEG) or `avc1` (H.264) for a camera. 20 bytes after that will be 4 bytes stored in little endian notation which indicate the frame rate. Skip another 4 bytes and then the next 4 bytes will be another little endian number which indicate the total number of video frames.

I'm looking at a sample AVI file right now where the numbers are: frame rate = 24 and # of frames = 0x37EB = 14315. This works out to 9m56s, which is accurate for this file.