# Question about getting duration of hosted video file in url

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping

I have been trying to web **scrape** the data (to be more specific, the lenght) of a hosted video. I have a link like "https://something.com/filename.mp4 so its just the video there. I am not an expert in this kind of thing, and only could parse the basic headers with this code:

```
import urllib.request
url="https://i.imgur.com/xsmX53B.mp4"
response =  urllib.request.urlopen(url)
print(response.getheader('slider'))
```

What I am trying to get is this value here: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6rPY.png). Any ideas on how to do this in Python?

Comment: That time signal is not part of the Html code. Rather, it is created by the software rendering/playing the video. Thus it can not be web scraped.
You might need to load the video and analyze it with a third-party solution. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144373/retrieve-video-file-duration-time-using-r

Comment: So you're downloading this video, right?

Comment: I was trying to not to download it, if it was possible.

Comment: 'To scrap' means to throw away, I think you mean __scrape__

Comment: Yeah! English is not my mother language so don´t expect much.